# Self joined Rails table allows adding association only one way

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, self-join

I have a problem with creating self referenced associations in my code. Generally the idea is that I have various workshop categories and that category may require another (you have to finish the first category to sign up for the 2nd). I have the following code for my models:

```
class WorkshopCategory < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :category_requirements, foreign_key: 'category_id', class_name: 'CategoryRequirement'
  has_many :requirements, through: :category_requirements
end

class CategoryRequirement < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :category, foreign_key: 'category_id', class_name: 'WorkshopCategory'
  belongs_to :requirement, foreign_key: 'requirement_id', class_name: 'WorkshopCategory'
end
```

and following migration for their tables:

```
class CreateWorkshopCategories < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :workshop_categories do |t|
       # some fields for workshop_categories
    end
  end
end

class CreateCategoryRequirements < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :category_requirements do |t|
      t.integer :category_id, index: true
      t.integer :requirement_id
    end
  end
end
```

I created some seeds and I have the following problem:

```
WorkshopCategory.find(2).requirements.create(requirement_id: 1)
```

results in error 'ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute 'requirement_id' for WorkshopCategory'.

while:

```
CategoryRequirement.create(category_id: 2, requirement_id: 1)
```

works properly and then WorkshopCategory.find(2).requirements also properly returns WorkshopCategory of id 1 as its requirement.

I may have misunderstood Rails guides as I am a beginner but as far as I know both ways should be working, correct? If yes, then what's wrong with my code? Why WorkshopCategory.find(2).requirements.create() operates on WorkshopCategory model instead of CategoryRequirement?

Comment: Add your category and requirement classes.

Comment: I don't have such classes, the given upon naming is dictated by other classes in my code but there are no dependencies yet. You can treat "WorkshopCategory" as Category.rb and "CategoryRequirement" as "Requirement.rb"

Comment: Which guide are you using?

Comment: Just official http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html There is such a creation of association mentioned there for standard has_many/belongs_to association so I assumed it should work in my case as well - hence the question.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, I had a wrong assumption. I did my associations code on the basis of the one provided here:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :friendships, :foreign_key => "person_id", 
      :class_name => "Friendship"

   has_many :friends, :through => :friendships
end

class Friendship < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :person, :foreign_key => "person_id", :class_name => "Person"
   belongs_to :friend, :foreign_key => "friend_id", :class_name => "Person"  
end
```

and although you can access sb's friends using Person.find(1).friends, you can't do Person.find(1).friends.create(friend_id: 2) as in this case you try to in fact create a new person - while what is needed is to create a friendship. So in case of the code above 2 ways of creating associations are:

```
Person.find(1).friendships.create(friend_id: 2)
# and
Friendships.create(person_id: 1, friend_id: 2)
```

and in my case these are:

```
WorkshopCategory.find(2).category_requirements.create(requirement_id: 1)
# and
CategoryRequirement.create(category_id: 2, requirement_id: 1)
```